# Drag and drop game sort items to three targets

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, target, cs4

Please I need some help. I have spent 2 weeks trying to make a drag and drop game In cs4 actionscript 3.0 and am about to give up.  I have gotten help so far, but the best suggestion I got was try and start from scratch instead of decompiling someone else's work. so here it is
I have an array that looks like this

```
var answername:Array = new Array();
var answerdest:Array = new Array();
answername[0] = "gravel";
answerdest[0] = "1";
answername[1] = "Nuts and boltsl";
answerdest[1] = "1";
answername[2] = "water";
answerdest[2] = "2";
answername[3] = "gold";
answerdest[3] = "3";
answername[4] = "Iron";
answerdest[4] = "3";
```

I need three targets,
and the ability to place the name of the item in my array (this is just a short piece of it) on the screen, if it is dropped on the target matching the answerdest number tor that item it is placed in a column, and the next item my array appears.  If not it returns to its starting position.  This seems like it should be easy to do but I am not a computer teacher I am a science teacher that is trying to make something for my student to use. I have basic coding skills for cs4.

This is as far as i have gotten but can not Figure out how to get the drag and drop part to check if it is in the correct spot. And get to to create a new drag-able  if the answer is correct.
I have created an answer target named "Answer1",

```
var objectoriginalX:Number;
var objectoriginalY:Number;

Atom.buttonMode = true;
Atom.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Atom.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

Matter.buttonMode = true;
Matter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Matter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.startDrag();
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
}       
var dropCount:int = 0;
var dbCount:int=0;
var dbutton0;
function dropObject (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    {
        event.target.stopDrag();
        var targetName = Answer1;
        trace (targetName);
        var matchingTarget:DisplayObject = getChildByName(targetName);
        if (event.target.dropTarget != null && event.target.dropTarget.parent == answerdest[1])
        {
            event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
            event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
            event.target.buttonMode = false;
            alpha = .8
            dropCount ++;
            event.target.x = 10
            event.target.y = (Number(dropCount) * 100);
            trace ("hit");
            trace (dropCount);
        } else 
        {
        event.target.x = 100;
        event.target.y = 111;
        trace ("miss");
        }
    } 
}

var answername:Array = new Array();
var answerdest:Array = new Array();
answername[0] = "gravel";
answerdest[0] = "1";
answername[1] = "Nuts and boltsl";
answerdest[1] = "Answer1";
answername[2] = "water";
answerdest[2] = "2";
answername[3] = "gold";
answerdest[3] = "3";
answername[4] = "Iron";
answerdest[4] = "3";
text3
text3.text = answername[1];

var myText:TextField = new TextField();
Atom.addChild(myText);
myText.text = answername[1] ;
```

Thanks for your help. I do not know if I am even on the correct track to do what I need it to do.

Comment: `event.target.parent.addChild(event.target)` what is that supposed to do? Because what it says is "make the child of the parent be the child of the parent". In other words it does nothing. So what is that line meant to do?

Answer (score 1):

**partial answer**

```
var answername:Array = new Array();
var answerdest:Array = new Array();
answername[0] = "gravel";
answerdest[0] = "1";
answername[1] = "Nuts and boltsl";
answerdest[1] = "Answer1";
answername[2] = "water";
answerdest[2] = "2";
answername[3] = "gold";
answerdest[3] = "3";
answername[4] = "Iron";
answerdest[4] = "3";
text3
text3.text = answername[1];
```

This is pretty messy. I'm going to show a slightly better way. Even my method here isn't the best, but it's similar enough to what you are doing to not be hard to adopt.

```
var answer:Array = [
    {_name:"gravel",dest:"1"},
    {_name:"Nuts and bolts",dest:"Answer1"},
    {_name:"water",dest:"2"},
    {_name:"gold",dest:"3"},
    {_name:"Iron",dest:"4"}
];
text3 // what is this supposed to do? I didn't get rid of it. But just a string sitting in the middle of your code should be throwing an error. I'd get rid of it. 
//text3.text = answername[1]; // now we have a better way!
text3.text = answer[1]._name;
```

I know this doesn't directly help solve your problem but let's clean up your code and eventually we will figure it out. I just couldn't explain this in just a comment.

```
var objectoriginalX:Number;
var objectoriginalY:Number; 

Atom.buttonMode = true;
Atom.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Atom.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

Matter.buttonMode = true;
Matter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
Matter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.startDrag(); 
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
}        
var dropCount:int = 0;
var dbCount:int=0;
var dbutton0;
function dropObject (event:MouseEvent):void
{
         event.target.stopDrag(); 
         var targetName = Answer1;
         trace (targetName);
         var matchingTarget:DisplayObject = getChildByName(targetName);
         if (event.target.dropTarget != null && event.target.dropTarget.parent == answer[1].dest) // red flag here! 
//dest is a String and .parent is a MovieClip. 
//They can never be equal. This block of code would never run like this. 
        {
            event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
            event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
            event.target.buttonMode = false;
            alpha = .8
            dropCount ++;
            event.target.x = 10
            event.target.y = (Number(dropCount) * 100);
            trace ("hit"); 
            trace (dropCount);
        } else 
        {
        event.target.x = 100;
        event.target.y = 111;
        trace ("miss");
        } 
} 

var answer:Array = [
    {_name:"gravel",dest:"1"},
    {_name:"Nuts and bolts",dest:"Answer1"},
    {_name:"water",dest:"2"},
    {_name:"gold",dest:"3"},
    {_name:"Iron",dest:"4"}
];
text3.text = answer[1]._name;

var myText:TextField = new TextField();
Atom.addChild(myText);
myText.text = answer[1]._name;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130496/discussion-on-answer-by-neal-davis-drag-and-drop-game-sort-items-to-three-target).